# There seems to be a bug with Tshark's -z conv,ip

Tags: tshark, crash

I've tried a lot to list `ip conversations` in a `.cap file with Tshark`. I can do this easily with `*wireshark -> statistics -> conversations -> "ipv4" lable*`, so I guess it's also easy to do so with Tshark:

```
tshark -n -r "d:\test\test.cap" -z conv,ip,"ip.len>50" -t ad
```

BUT, After all message printed, `tshark crashed : Tshark has stopped working.`

Is there really a bug with tshark? ... or with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something! The problem is that I use `-t ad` expression:

> **ad** absolute with date: The absolute date, displayed as YYYY-MM-DD, and time, as local time in your time zone, is the actual time and date
>   the packet was captured

When I change to `-t r` expression:

> **r** relative: The relative time is the time elapsed between the first
>   packet and the current packet

tshark won't crash, and the ralative time is a negative number, like "-6063.000000"!

So I guess `-t ad` is the arch-criminal. However, when I use `-z conv,tcp,[filter]`, Tshark won't crash.

!!!!!!! `-z conv,ip,[filter]` + `-t ad` + `negative number time` = `BUG`??!!

Comment: Which version do you use?
TShark doesn't crash, when I use the latest version:
tshark -v
TShark 1.12.7 (v1.12.7-0-g7fc8978 from master-1.12).

You can download the latest version [here](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

BTW:
TShark does crash, when I use an older version:
tshark -v
TShark 1.10.3 (SVN Rev 53022 from /trunk-1.10)

Comment: I do use the latest version: `wireshark -v` -> `wireshark 1.12.7 (v1.12.7-0-g7fc8978 from master-1.12)`. My Tshark keep on crashing after I reinstall it.

Comment: I did a few more tests. It only works fine on a tiny (100KB) sample file... TShark 1.12.7 also crashes on a 3MB file, when using the option -t ad.
BTW Why are you using this option?

Comment: Because absolute date displayed as `YYYY-MM-DD` is human readable. My boss won't be happy to read relative time like "1000.0000", "3500.0000", etc...

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug related to [bug 1850](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1850).
See also this question about [Absolute time and time resolution in tshark I/O statistics](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8233/absolute-time-and-time-resolution-in-tshark-io-statistics)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option -q:
When reading a capture file, or when capturing and not saving to a file, don't print packet information; this is useful if you're using a -z option to calculate statistics and don't want the packet information printed, just the statistics.

tshark -r test2905a.pcap -q -z conv,ip,"ip.len>50"

See the [man-page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information.

Comment: I've already tried your solution, but the bug is still there no matter `-q` comes or not.

Comment: You are right. A tiny file seems to work, but this is the output: tshark -r test2905a.pcap -z conv,ip,"ip.len>50" -t ad
20.34.40.25         <-> 10.110.1.10              97      8076      97     17433     194     25509  1970-01-01 01:00:00         2,3083
10.110.1.10         <-> 10.34.136.136            11      5453       9      2271      20      7724  1970-01-01 01:00:00         4,8492.